# Wordpress Template Reverts to default template after changing

Tags: templates, memory, plugin-wp-supercache

I am experiencing a problem regarding wordpress page template. after I change the wordpress template to "Home Page", it reverts to default template after update. I tried installing WP Super Cache then purging cache, but still no luck. I also Increased memory limit in server but still reverts to default. are there any fix to this? your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It could be CDN caching. Does the template revert on the backend or just the frontend? Could you provide more information to help clarify your problem? Where is the site hosted? What response headers do you get when visiting the page?

Comment: yup only in the backend. when I change template, it reverts to default so the fields for that page template is not reflecting on frontend.